# IPS attack message error when I visit a website

Tags: security, debian, debian-wheezy

I'm on debian wheezy, I have visited a [website](http://www.medi1tv.com/ar/%D9%88%D8%B2%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%AE%D9%84%D9%8A%D8%A9-%D8%B9%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%B5%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AC%D9%8A%D8%B4-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AC%D8%B2%D8%A7%D8%A6%D8%B1%D9%8A-%D8%A3%D8%B7%D9%84%D9%82%D8%AA-%D8%B9%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%A9-%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%AA%D8%AC%D8%A7%D9%87-%D9%85%D8%B1%D9%83%D8%B2-%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%82%D8%A8%D8%A9-%D9%85%D8%BA%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%8A-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D8%BA%D8%B1%D8%A8-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%8A-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D8%AE%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B1-22495) but this one show me an error that I'm blocked because of IPS attack, the error is:

```
Blocked because of IPS attack, An attack was detected, originating from your 
system. Please contact the system administrator.
```

When I have searched what this means I found that my computer is infected if I have this error message and I should use a spyware scanner, but it seems there is no spyware for Linux. Second thing: I already used my visa card in this computer, am I in danger? What's the solution?

Note: My IP is dynamic, not fixed.

Comment: This means that it could just be an IP Address near yours in the range in which your ISP provides. It doesn't necessarily have anything to do with you. You can contact the owner of the site you wish to visit and see if they can unblock your IP specifically.

Comment: i log out and connected again,my ip is changed and the website work now without problem, do you thing it's not a security issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are spyware on linux (well, there are rootkit) and a Debian can be compromised.
You can try for example [chkrootkit](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/chkrootkit) or [rkhunter](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=names&keywords=rkhunter) to test it.

That said, as kobaltz told you in the comment, the more probable is that you IP has been used by someone with some spyware. The site you visit has blacklisted the IP, and hadn't seen that the user behind the IP is not the same anymore.